# "Video unavailable" issue when using iFrame to show YouTube videos

Tags: angular, google-chrome, iframe, youtube, angular7

When I use an iframe to show YouTube videos in my Angular 7 project, some of the videos show a "Video unavailable" error.
[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCxQW.png)

Sample code of iframe with error:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dhYOPzcsbGM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is an unedited code from YouTube -> Share -> Embed (So nothing wrong with the code)

This will work perfectly well when running in localhost, but isn't working in my dev or production environment. Also note, it won't work in http://127.0.0.1:4200/

Things I've tried & found,

- Works in Edge browser (Even in production,  surprisingly).
- Not working in Chrome & Firefox.
- If you replace the src of iframe example in w3schools, it will work. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp (So it can work in a non local env).
- Issue isn't caused by the owner of the video restricting embedding. Because in that case, below the "Video unavailable", it will clearly mention the cause.
- I've tried running it in a brand new project. So, issue is not caused by any packages or faults in my original project.
- I get this warning,

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at
>   http://www.youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A
>   future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site
>   requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can
>   review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies
>   and see more details at
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

P.S. I'm a mid level noob at Angular, please be elaborate with your answers. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The `SameSite` cookie warnings are related to the upcoming changes that will apply `SameSite=Lax` by default. However, these may not be applied in your browser right now, so I suspect there's another issue here.

You can check your browser's behaviour on https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me - if everything is green then the new restrictions are being applied. However, I tried your example code here: https://thrilling-zucchini.glitch.me/ with the `SameSite` restrictions both enabled and disabled and it worked.

Comment: Hi @rowan_m, thank you for the help. Can you go to that video's YouTube page, click share, choose embed, then copy just the src and open that in a new tab. to me it shows "Video unavailable". Its the same if I place that iframe in my project.

This is the src by the way : https://www.youtube.com/embed/dhYOPzcsbGM